# Technique for using SOLID Open/Closed Principle with enums and validation

Tags: c#, enums, open-closed-principle

I am searching for the best technique to use to ensure that I follow the Open/Closed Principle in the following situation.

Essentially, I have inherited some code that is a nightmare to extend as it requires so many modifications:

```
public enum Basis {
 Basis1,
 Basis2
}

public class BenefitA {
 public Basis Basis {get;set;}
 public int Amount {get;set;}
}

public class BenefitB {
 public Basis Basis {get;set;}
 public int Amount {get;set;}
}

public class RequestA {
 public BenefitA {get;set;}
 public int Age {get;set;}

 public bool Validate()
 {
  if (BenefitA.Basis == Basis.Basis1 && Age > 50)
  {
   return false;
  }
  else if (BenefitA.Basis == Basis.Basis2 && Age < 50)
  {
   return false;
  }
  return true;
 }
}
```

Imagine that there are many more benefits and many more requests and I need to add a third value to the Basis enum.

I now have to go in to all of the Requests and write new logic for the new value.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: I assume that other requests, e.g. `RequestB`, will validate differently, right? For example, they might base the validation on a property other than `Age` or might use in a different way, right?

Comment: By "a better way of doing this" do you mean "in general" or in this specific case? If the code is a "nightmare to extend" it's going to be a big task to rewrite, so your options are limited: there's a new value, and it needs to be catered for..

Comment: Yeah RequestB may validate differently, to be honest we have lots of code that uses lots of enums and every time a new value is added there are lots of areas to change, risking that we miss something.

I suppose I am searching for design patterns that help with this type of scenario.

It may be too big of a task to rewrite this now, but if I can implement a design pattern for future code this would be a good result.

Comment: @CraigBroadman, you should research strategy pattern.